mysql downgrade version kali linux
10.11.6-MariaDB-2 I have this version of mysql
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT VERSION()
    -> ;
+-------------------+
| VERSION()         |
+-------------------+
| 10.11.6-MariaDB-2 |
+-------------------+

Yet I want to downgrade this to mysql:8.0.28-oracle
I downloaded this version with  wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.28-1_all.deb
Then I try to install it:
└─# sudo apt install ./mysql-apt-config_0.8.28-1_all.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'mysql-apt-config' instead of './mysql-apt-config_0.8.28-1_all.deb'
mysql-apt-config is already the newest version (0.8.28-1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libatk-adaptor python3-pyatspi
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Yet the running mysql service version() command outputs like above. What is the issue ?
I am using kali linux.


You're trying to use ubuntu/debian package repositories on Kali. As Kali documentation says, that doesn't work, in general; Kali is not debian nor ubuntu.
You're trying to install a database server on Kali. Wrong operating system, says Kali itself, so this is unsupported by both MySQL and Kali. Kali is a special-purpose tool. Installing MySQL on Kali is like taking your combine harvester to go to the grocery store and buy a pound of butter. Nice, specialized tool you have, but you're using it for the wrong job.
You're trying to downgrade to a surprisingly specific version of Mysql. That might indicate you're doing something wrong, like trying to use software that was built against a different set of libraries than you have. Again, this sounds like a problem of you using the wrong operating system. The bad news is that even a specific version of a software won't inherently solve all ABI incompatibilities; you need the same build flags, the same standard library version, the same dependency versions… If you're not installing that version for ABI reasons, but to say, analyze it for security reasons, Kali is still the wrong platform for that (not a covert pentesting!), and you would need to install your MySQL version in a VM or at least a container that really is the same environment that someone would use that MySQL version in. So, probably, one of the officially supported platforms, according to MySQL!

So, the correct solution is to

Switch to an operating system that even tries to make databases etc work. Good choices, if you already know Kali, are debian or Ubuntu.
Preferably, install MariaDB instead of the upstream MySQL on that other operating system, because

you don't need to add any third party repositories then, apt install mariadb, done
It's the community-maintained fork of MySQL, which is fully compatible, aside from a few "Business" features that you don't need unless you're administrating a full fleet of database servers.


If you're actually in need of that version of actual MySQL, figure out on which platforms MySQL suggests you run it, and run it in a VM that has exactly such a platform.

Again, your main problem here is that you're abusing Kali as a general purpose operating system, which even the Kali documentation says you shouldn't. We can't really help you with that as much as we'd like to.

You stopped at step 1 of the installation instructions, which only sets up the repository. You need to continue with the subsequent steps.
As Marcus Müller says, Kali Linux isn’t appropriate for this.
